# Как получить сегодняшнюю дату и время + 12 месяцев в формате "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java

Я получаю сегодняшнюю дату но не знаю как ее отформатировать вот мой код.

```
LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(12);
```

Мне необходимо чтоб дата и время были в формате "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не получится. LocalDate хранит только дату, а ваш шаблон предусматривает, что вы выводите и время тоже. Посему сделайте так

```
LocalDateTime futureDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(12); 
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dtf.format(futureDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.dd.MM    HH:mm:ss");
String a = dateFormat.format(futureDate);
```